# Blazor re-rendering components blocks elements

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm little bit stuck on my index page loading everything from my excel page.
Each item has an edit button and delete button like I used in mvc. I can delete 1 item where i later call 'StateHasChanged()' however when I like to delete another one nothing happens nor do I come into my code.

my html:

```
@if (clients == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <div>
        <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#taskModal" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Client" @onclick="(() => AddClient())" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>                
                <th><span @onclick="@(() => Sort("RefId"))">Id</span><i class="@(SortIndicator("RefId"))"></i></th>
                <th><span @onclick="@(() => Sort("FirstName"))">First Name</span><i class="@(SortIndicator("FirstName"))"></i></th>
                <th><span @onclick="@(() => Sort("LastName"))">Last Name</span><i class="@(SortIndicator("LastName"))"></i></th>
                <th><span @onclick="@(() => Sort("Address"))">Address</span><i class="@(SortIndicator("Address"))"></i></th>
                <th><span @onclick="@(() => Sort("Company"))">Company</span><i class="@(SortIndicator("Company"))"></i></th>
                <th><span @onclick="@(() => Sort("VATNumber"))">Vat number</span><i class="@(SortIndicator("VATNumber"))"></i></th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (ClientDto item in clients)
            {
            <tr>                
                <td>@item.RefId</td>
                <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                <td>@item.LastName</td>
                <td>@item.Address</td>
                <td>@item.Company</td>
                <td>@item.VatNumber</td>
                <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => EditClient(item))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#taskModal" value="Edit" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="(() => Delete_Click(item.RefId))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDelteModal" value="Delete" /></td>
                <Confirm @ref="DeleteConfirmation" ConfirmationChanged="ConfirmDelete_Click" ConfirmMessage="@($"Are you sure you want to delete this client!")"></Confirm>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

<Pager PageIndex=@paginatedList.PageIndex TotalPages=@paginatedList.TotalPages OnClick="PageIndexChanged"
       HasNextPage=@paginatedList.HasNextPage HasPreviousPage=@paginatedList.HasPreviousPage>
</Pager>
```

my code:

```
IEnumerable<ClientDto> clients;
PaginatedList<ClientDto> paginatedList = new PaginatedList<ClientDto>();    

int? pageNumber = 1;
string currentSortField = "RefId";
string currentSortOrder = "Asc";


protected ConfirmationComponent DeleteConfirmation { get; set; }

private int RefId { get; set; }


protected void Delete_Click(int refId)
{
    RefId = refId;
    DeleteConfirmation.Show();
}

protected void ConfirmDelete_Click(bool deleteConfirmed)
{
    if(deleteConfirmed)
    {
        DeleteClient(RefId);
        //reload client list
        paginatedList = ClientService.ClientReader(1, currentSortField, currentSortOrder);
        clients = paginatedList.Items;
    }
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Log.Information("Initializing clients");
    paginatedList = ClientService.ClientReader(1, currentSortField, currentSortOrder);
    clients = paginatedList.Items;
}     

private void AddClient()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/addclient");
}

private void EditClient(ClientDto client)
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/editclient/" + client.RefId);
}

private void DeleteClient(int clientId)
{
    Log.Information($"Client with id: {clientId} has been deleted");
    ClientService.DeleteClient(clientId);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

In this last method StateHasChanged() is being called and yes I do real-time see item disappeared and is deleted, but when I click on delete again in another item nothing happens not even when i put a breakpoint in my 'confirmation_delete' method. so i does seem like nothing is happening also i don't get the delete popup box either.

Comment: Where does `<Confirm  />` come from?  Is Delete_Click() hit the second time?

Comment: Please try to add `<EditForm Model=[Yourmodel]>` arround you inputs!

Comment: @user13256346 i do have it I snaped a snapshot, but my form is wrapped in editform

Comment: @HenkHolterman custom component

Comment: @TechnologyResearcher, OK, try to use `@Key` inside you inputs to tell the component that your value has been changed!

Comment: The symptoms point to a problem inside the `<Confirm />` comp. You still do not tell us about a breakpoint in the other method.

Comment: @HenkHolterman well I can't put a breakpoint at the confirm component. I can put a breakpoinyt in the Confirm_delete method and no it doesn't come there, so yes to problem is probably at the confirm or something there, I just don't know why it doesn't come there after rerendering

Comment: @HenkHolterman no it doesn't hit the second time, the confirm component is not something I made up I made it form this website: https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/delete-confirmation-dialog-in-blazor/

Comment: @user13256346 the @key="item" works I can delete multiple times, Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@key` to optimize Blazor performance, it will create a value for each element and Blazor can use this values to compare the existing items with the new ones, so Blazor can see the changes better and render the the components.